# Crossed folders in eclipse luna

Tags: c++, eclipse, project

I've just installed Eclipse Luna and in my project explorer there are appearing some folders crossed out, and I don't know how to remove it and even what it means.

[image]

Looks like the Engine and Gameplay folders are also being duplicated. What is going on?

Thanks

Comment: The red 'x' means "something is wrong": http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm while the diagonal line means the element is deprecated. Take a look at those files and see where the errors are.

Comment: Yeah, I was refering to the diagonal line. How can it be deprecated? Those classes are mine and I didn't say anything about them. How can I disable it?

Comment: Search for "deprecated" into project preferences. I have no idea why those are deprecated, post some code perhaps

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar (the same?) issue after creating a new folder in an existing project. Having found this (incredibly slowly-loading) [documentation page](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_cproj_view.htm), I figured out the gray diagonal line in CDT can actually also mean "excluded from build".

This was readily countered by right-clicking on the folder in the project explorer, choosing

**Resource Configurations -> Exclude from Build...**

and then deselecting all configurations.

Comment: It's not always easy to tell, but as the answer suggests, you're only editing the "exlusion properties" for the folder, not for the whole project.

Answer (score 6):

What I did was go to:

**Project properties ->C/C++ General ->Paths and Symbols**

There I added the folder to the include directories and at the **Source Location Tab** I clicked on:

**Edit filter -> Remove**

I think it has to do with how you added the folder to the project (through eclipse, as a source folder or externally)

Comment: I burned a lot of cycles trying to fix this and then found your answer - success! Thank you Niko